# Vertical arrow meaning in math?

Tags: calculus, functions

What does the symbol $\uparrow$ in this context means:

Consider a function $f$ of $x$, $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a set $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Let $1_G:=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x\in G\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

What is the function $f \uparrow 1_G$?

Comment: This is not any standard notation I've ever seen.  Can you say more about the context?

Comment: It's in the book "Asymptotic statistics" by van der Vaart p. 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(f_n)$ is a *sequence* of functions and $g$ is a function, then the notation $f_n\uparrow g$ means that the sequence $(f_n)$ is monotone increasing and converges to $g$.  It's just a variant on the usual notation $f_n\to g$ for "$(f_n)$ converges to $g$".